# log output of apt-get in shell

Tags: shell, apt

I am using `apt-get` via exec in my go program.  Like this:

```
func aptInstall(pkg, ver string) {
    args := []string{"install", "-y", fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", pkg, ver)}
    cmd := exec.Command("apt-get", args...)
    cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), "LANG=en")
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    log("apt install", "cmd", fmt.Sprintf("apt-get %s",
        strings.Join(args, " ")), "out", string(out), "err", err)
}
```

The logged message contains:

```
    Selecting previously unselected package nnrforms.
    (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 219690 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../nnrforms_531-82a94c0_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking nnrforms (531-82a94c0) ...
    Setting up nnrforms (531-82a94c0) ...
    [0;1;31mFailed to reload nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not found.[0m
```

How can I tell `apt-get` that it is not running in interactive mode, and suppress progress messages like `Reading database ...` and do not add ANSI-ESC colorization?

### **Updated**

Tried the two answers, colorization is removed by set `TERM=dumb`, but progress information remains:

```
- 20230518_144401.646+0800: apt install
  cmd: apt-get install -qqqy -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="0" -o APT::Color="0" -o Dpkg::Use-Pty="0" a2up=72-5683a16
  err: <nil>
  out: 
- 20230518_144414.275+0800: apt remove
  cmd: apt-get remove -qqqy -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="0" -o APT::Color="0" -o Dpkg::Use-Pty="0" a2s
  err: exit status 100
  out: |
    (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 219699 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing a2up (72-5683a16) ...
    Failed to disable unit: Unit file a2up.service does not exist.
    dpkg: error processing package a2up (--remove):
     installed a2up package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: too many errors, stopping
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     a2up
    Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Note that `-qqqy` suppressed most output message for `apt-get install`, but seems not working for `apt-get remove`?

Answer (score 2):

You control the verbosity of the output with `-q`, `-qq` and `-qqq` and to suppress warnings `2>/dev/null`

```
sudo apt install neofetch -yq -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="0" -o APT::Color="0" -o Dpkg::Use-Pty="0" 2> /dev/null
```

`-o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="0"` disbales the progress bar

`-o APT::Color="0"` disables the usage of colors

`-o Dpkg::Use-Pty="0"` hides the `Reading database` message

I run

```
sudo apt install neofetch -yq -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="0" -o APT::Color="0" -o Dpkg::Use-Pty="0" 2> /dev/null > out
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: And setting `TERM` to `dumb` will disable colourisation of `systemctl` messages.

Comment: it only suppressed progress message in the console, but log file still contains this message

Comment: @xrfang unfortunately it doesn’t seem [possible to suppress the progress messages from `dpkg`](https://bugs.debian.org/539617) if the output claims to be a terminal, which seems to be the case with Go `exec`.

Comment: @StephenKitt I don't understand your last comment about Go's exec... I have set the command's stdout/stderr to a byte stream which is of course not a tty, but that makes no difference.

Comment: @xrfang given that `dpkg` checks whether its output is a terminal, and is supposed to skip progress reports when it isn’t, I assumed that Go’s `exec` set up an environment where the running program would be given a (virtual) terminal for its output. However I checked Go’s behaviour and that is incorrect, so I don’t know why `dpkg` isn’t behaving correctly here...