# apt-get -y -qq install isn't silent (output incoming like: "Processing triggers for man-db"). Why? I don't want to terminate statements by > /dev/null

Tags: apt

I'm provisioning a vagrantbox with a small script running few steps.
Most are performing `apt-get -y -qq install` and `update`

```ruby
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
   sh 050_Certificats.sh
   sh 070_Utilitaires.sh
   sh 100_JDK.sh "17"
   sh 150_Postgresql-Postgis.sh "15" "3"
   sh 200_NodeJS-Angular.sh "16"
   sh 250_ELK.sh "7.x"
   sh 300_Kafka.sh "3.4.0" "2.12"
   sh 350_Geoserver.sh "2.23.1"
SHELL
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "050 : Installation des certificats et mise à jour"

sudo apt-get -y -qq install gnupg2 wget ca-certificates
sudo apt-get -y -qq update
```

But the `apt-get -y -qq install` statements aren't silent on the output (`apt-get -y -qq update` are...). And I would like to avoid the need of terminating my statements by `> /dev/null`:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
    default: 050 : Installation des certificats et mise à jour
    default: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
    default: Selecting previously unselected package gnupg2.
    default: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 65%abase ... 5%
    default: (Reading database ... 70%
    default: (Reading database ... 75%
    default: (Reading database ... 80%
    default: (Reading database ... 85%
    default: (Reading database ... 90%
    default: (Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 68876 files and directories currently installed.)
    default: Preparing to unpack .../gnupg2_2.2.27-2+deb11u2_all.deb ...
    default: Unpacking gnupg2 (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
    default: Setting up gnupg2 (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...
    default: Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
```

Comment: Do you require any of the reported lines, and how do you differentiate the two groups? Why not merely redirect the whole of stdout and stderr to a log file at the outermost level (for possible later reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-q` controls `apt-get`’s output, but there are many other programs involved in package installation, all of which can produce output: `dpkg` itself, maintainer scripts etc.

You can reduce the amount of output produced by `dpkg` by disabling its progress information:

```
sudo apt-get -y -qq install -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="0" -o APT::Color="0" -o Dpkg::Use-Pty="0" ...
```

See [log output of apt-get in shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/746219/86440) for details.

Incidentally, you should run `apt-get update` *before* trying to install or upgrade anything.

Comment: Thanks! The `apt-get update` after `apt-get install` is to refresh certificates.

Comment: `update` only refreshes the local copies of repository package lists (and related information), none of that is affected by certificates. Anyway, since this is the first script run while provisioning your VM, you should run `update` before `install` to ensure that the local repository information is up-to-date.